# When is flock() really needed?

Tags: php, locking

I think a file locking mechanism should be used whenever there are possible concurrent reads and/or updates to a file.

However, I see for instance that the Monolog handler StreamHandler doesn't flock() the file, what about multiple concurrent writes?
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php

Another example would be Laravel's Filesystem class:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php

Comment: How would those libraries produce concurrent writes? PHP is single threaded by default, so you can't produce concurrent writes unless you somehow parallelize explicitly -- either at the process or the system level. Is that the answer you want?

Comment: @Jon I must be confusing threading with concurrent programming (in this context simultaenous http requests), right? So you're saying that concurrent writes can't occur in asynchronous http requests.

Comment: Sure, they can occur. But these pieces of code don't know that there are concurrent HTTP requests (or any HTTP requests at all for that matter) and that they are all writing to the same file, so they don't lock. If you want to lock, wrap them in something appropriate.

Comment: sorry @Jon didn't understand your last comment. First you say "How would those libraries produce concurrent writes?" then you say "Sure, they can occur" (talking about simultaneous http requests, not parallelization of process), which seems the opposite. Then you say that the code doesn't know if requests are writing to the same file, well that's why I asked if I should use flock().
According to your first comment, I shouldn't need to flock().

Comment: Yes, you should use `flock` in this scenario. The confusion is because the question is not clear at all -- you have more information in mind than you say out loud. "What about multiple concurrent writes?" can be interpreted in more than one way. For example, "Why don't these libraries `flock` to make sure they work correctly even in the presence of multiple concurrent writes?".

Comment: These frameworks seem to have even more basic problems. `StreamHandler\write()` does not check the return values of `fwrite()`. So in case of disk issues, bad permissions (ACL) or other problems, you'll lose data without knowing. `Filesystem\get()` checks if the target is a file, but not if it is readable. So it might return `FALSE` instead of a string. `prepend` of course does not check this. Data loss again.

Comment: How many programmers/libraries use Monolog to log to a file? How many programmers use Laravel's Filesystem and Cache/FileStore classes? I bet no one wrap them (as you mentionned above) to make sure they work correctly for multiple concurrent writes (e.g. using flock()) And nobody seems to complain about concurrency (I google'd a lot) **or even talk about it**. That still keeps me confused.

Comment: `flock()` is always required when using the `shepherd()` function.

Comment: Why you mention Laravel's Filesystem as second example? **It uses flock**.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit vague, but I still try to answer.

1) no writer, multiple readers

This case does not need any locking as no data is changed.

2) one writer, multiple readers (none, one or more)

Without disk errors, the file won't get corrupt on disk. But it can get corrupt for the reader. A simple example: You write the string `test failed not`. The reader might read `test failed`, as it read the file before `not` was written. If this is a problem, you need locking.

3) multiple writers, multiple readers (none, one or more)

Here, the file can even get corrupt on disk. Imagine two writers: The first one tries to write `test failed not`. The second tries to write the same. Due to context switches, you might end up with `test failed` and `test failed not not`. So you need locking.

Now some details:

Usually, the file system writes in blocks. A block might be 4k in size. So anything below that size is written atomically. This again means, that people who just log data in chunks of less than 4k, never have this problem and seem to not care.

So basically, you do not even want to lock. You just want atomic writes. As the file system (kernel) does not guarantee those, you have to implement them yourself. So you require locking. And `flock()` is just one possibility to create and manage locks.